Event email confirmation text not updating
One of our users updated the email confirmation text on an event and they email recieved contained the old text. I tested it again later and got the correct text. Assuming that the text is being cached, is there a way to prevent this? Or does anyone know of something else that might be causing this?
Best wishes
Jonny

DO you mean the event text in the 'confirmation email' on the Online Registration tab at eg https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/manage/registration?reset=1&action=update&id=3

Yes that's right. I don't have access to the demo you posted but that's the correct end point. In the database the field is 'confirm_email_text'

Re "I don't have access to the demo" - everyone does, it's a public demo but you need to login.  Details on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ front page

Thanks, didn't spot the credentials there. Confirm that yes, we're talking about the same field
